# Question regarding iPhone error

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

when i run my below code it gives this response on my device....

```
- (void) requestProductData
{
 //
 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"com.mycompany.inapppurchasetesting.productid"];//Same as the Product Id displayed in Itunes Connect//"]; 

 SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:str]]; 

 request.delegate = self;

 [request start];
 //
 //NSSet *productIDs = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.mycompany.inapppurchasetesting.productid", nil];

 //SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIDs];

 //request.delegate = self;

 NSLog(@"Requesting");

 //[request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;

 NSArray *myInvalidProducts = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

 NSLog(@"Did recieve response");

    NSLog(@"Response count is %d",response.products.count);
 NSLog(@"Invalid response count is %d",response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count);

 for (int i = 0; i<myProduct.count; i++)
 {
  NSLog(@"t:%@",[[myProduct objectAtIndex:i] localizedTitle]);
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < myInvalidProducts.count; ++i)
 {
  NSLog(@"Invalid products:%@",[[myInvalidProducts objectAtIndex:i] localizedTitle]);
    }

 // populate UI
 [request autorelease];
}
```

2010-11-16 14:14:46.028 InAppPurchaseTesting[7357:307] View is loaded

2010-11-16 14:14:46.164 InAppPurchaseTesting[7357:307] Requesting

2010-11-16 14:14:46.196 InAppPurchaseTesting[7357:307] can make payments

2010-11-16 14:14:52.135 InAppPurchaseTesting[7357:307] Did recieve response

2010-11-16 14:14:52.146 InAppPurchaseTesting[7357:307] Response count is 0

2010-11-16 14:14:52.152 InAppPurchaseTesting[7357:307] Invalid response count is 1

2010-11-16 14:14:52.160 InAppPurchaseTesting[7357:307] -[NSCFString localizedTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x114990

2010-11-16 14:14:52.181 InAppPurchaseTesting[7357:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString localizedTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x114990'

why the above error occurs...

please guide me out...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `invalidProductIdentifiers` only contains an array of `NSString`s, not `SKProduct`s.

[See the StoreKit documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsResponse/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSLog(@"Invalid products:%@",[myInvalidProducts objectAtIndex:i]);
```

Comment: What do you need to show? Since the productIdentifiers are invalid, you can only show the productIdentifier, not the localization. See my edited answer.

Comment: @joseph;thanks for the reply...what i asked you is can you pls show what is the error in my code..it is not showing the products...since its returning 0 count

Comment: What is the value of the one invalid productIdentifier that gets returned? It should be the same as the one you are sending. Are you sure it has the status "cleared for sale" in iTunes connect?

You have some minor flaws in your code that have nothing to do with the problem (e.g. count is not a property, and should be [response.products count], and stringWithFormat is not needed as you are simply providing a string).

Comment: Hmm... have you checked that your bundle id in your Info.plist corresponds with the one in iTunes connect?

Comment: It's hard to do debug this remotely, really. If these ids are correct, and you are using a productIdentifier that matches the one in iTunes connect 100% and that product is cleared for sale, I am stumped. Maybe you should put that in another question, though. Because it may not have anything to do with the code you posted.

Comment: Also make sure to read through these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=invalidproductidentifiers

Comment: @joseph: Thanks a lot for all your help..can you pls provide me some code to connect to the app store and getting product related informations.being a new to iPhone development i finding hard time to go further...thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think you are doing it fundamentally wrong codewise... so there is probably something else at fault.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you trying to call "localizedTitle" on NSCFString instead of a Product?